# MongoDB search big data collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying search through big data collection of objects (1 000 000 000 elements). 
Sample element looks like this:

```
Document{{_id=588e6f317367651f34a06c2c, busId=34, time=1262305558050, createdDate=Sun Jan 29 23:39:42 CET 2017}}
```

there are busIds from 0 to 300 and time increment about 30 milisecond on each record begins from

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"); 
long startDate = sdf.parse("2010.01.01 00:00:00").getTime();`

Now I am looking for all data with this query:

```
    BasicDBObject gtQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("busId", vehicleId));
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", startDate.getTime()).append("$lt", endDate.getTime())));
    gtQuery.put("$and", obj);
    System.out.println(gtQuery.toString());
    FindIterable<Document> curs = collection.find(gtQuery);
```

gtQuery output:

`{ "$and" : [ { "busId" : "34"} , { "time" : { "$gt" : 1262304705000 , "$lt" : 1262308305000}}]}`

Query is working but in this way it iterates over whole 1 000 000 000 elements in collection. 
Is there any way to do it faster?

Comment: `db.collection.createIndex({busId : 1, time : 1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/) on busId and time as suggested by @ares